# Инициализация массива в управляемой памяти C++

Tags: наследование, c++-cli, консоль

### abstract_classes.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "class_word.h"
using namespace System;


ref class notion abstract {
protected:
    String ^ _language;
    String ^ _inscription;
    String ^ _meaning;
    int _id;

public:
    notion(String ^ lng, String ^ inscr, String ^ mnng) :
        _language(lng), _inscription(inscr), _meaning(mnng) { }

    virtual int print() abstract;
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
ref class vocabulary {
private:
    array<notion ^> ^ntn_array;

public:
    vocabulary();
    void set_array(String ^file_path, String ^lng);
};

inline vocabulary::vocabulary() { ntn_array = nullptr; }
inline void vocabulary::set_array(String ^file_path, String ^lng) {
    array<String ^> ^whole = IO::File::ReadAllLines(file_path);

    ntn_array = gcnew array<notion ^>(whole->Length); // allocate memory

    for(int i = 0; i < whole->Length; ++i) {
        array<String ^> ^current = whole[i]->Split('#');

        // THE ERROR HERE BELOW
        ntn_array[i] = gcnew word(lng, current[0], current[2], current[3]);
    }
}
```

### class_word.h

```
#pragma once
#include "abstract_classes.h"

ref class word : public notion {
    String ^example;
    static int counter = 0;

public:
    word():notion("","","") { };
    word(String ^lng, String ^inscr, String ^mnng, String ^expl) :
        notion(lng, inscr, mnng), example(expl) { _id = ++counter; }

    virtual int print() override {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "abstrace_classes.h"

int main() {



    return 0;
}
```

### Проблема:

Из файла грузятся данные построчно в массив типа `String ^`.
Поэлементно каждая строка разбивается на подстроки и кладется в массив `current` тоже типа `String ^`
Класс `vocabulary` - контейнерный для абстрактного `notion`, от которого унаследован `word`.
Дело даже до создания экземпляров не доходит в файле `main.cpp`.
В методе `set_array` класса `vocabulary` выдает ошибку:

> Значение типа `word ^` нельзя присвоить сущности типа `notion ^`

А я хочу в указатель на абстрактный класс присвоить ссылку на дочерний. Может дело в дескрипторах? Как использовать ссылку а не дескриптор?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все объявления и реализацию классов надо поместить в один файл. Компилируется без ошибок.
Похоже, не видят они друг друга в разных файлах.